# $E \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $E$ is compact implies $E$ is closed and bounded (Proof)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to prove one half of the Heine-Borel theorem. I have proven that compact subsets of metric spaces are closed, so $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a metric space with the Euclidean distance as the metric and $E$ is closed. For the boundedness, I have come up with the following proof.

Assume that $E$ is compact but unbounded. This means there aren't any $p \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $M > 0$ such that $\forall x \in E$, $||p-x|| < M$. I pick a $x \in E$ and build the following collection of sets: $\{N_n(x)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}=\{N_1(x), N_2(x), \dots \}$, where $N_n(x)$ is the neighborhood of $x$ with the radius $n$. Then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}N_n(x)$ is an open cover of $E$, since for any $y \in E$, we have a $N_n(x)$, such that $||x-y|| < n$ and $y \in N_n(x)$ hence $ y \in \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}N_n(x)$. (And open, since each neighborhood is open). Then we have to show that no finite subcover of the collection $\{N_1(x), N_2(x), \dots \}$ for $E$ exists. Assume that a finite subcollection of $\{N_n(x)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ exists, such that $E \subset N_{n_1}(x) \cup \dots \cup N_{n_m}(x)$. Let $r=\max\{n_1, \dots, n_m \}$. Since $E$ is unbounded, there is a point $y \in E$ such that $||x-y||>r$ and hence $y \notin N_{n_1}(x) \cup \dots \cup N_{n_m}(x)$. This means that we cannot propose a finite subcollection from $\{N_n(x)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ to cover $E$, which contradicts with $E$ being compact.

It this proof valid? If not, how it can be improved, made correct?

Comment: As a matter of style, instead of a proof by contradiction, modify  it to say that   if  $E$ is any unbounded set  then for any $x\in E$ the open cover $\{N_n(x): n\in \mathbb N\}$ of $E$ has no finite subcover, so $E$ is not compact..... Note that this applies to any metric space:  Closed and bounded is necessary (but not always sufficient) for compactness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is fine. It can also be phrased as a direct proof. Notice that if there exists a finite subcover, it can be chosen to consist of a single neighborhood, namely the largest one, say $N_M(x)$. Then $E$ is completely contained in a ball of finite radius and therefore is bounded.

Comment: The theorem and proof generalize to show every compact set of a metric space can be contained in an open set of finite radius.